# Попытка установки pyqt5 с помощью pip3

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pip

Пытался установить PyQt5:

```
pip install PyQt5
```

И получил ошибку

```
Collecting PyQt5

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt5
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

ОС: Linux Mint;
Интерпретатор: python 3.6
Почему не устанавливается пакет? Покопался в инете, вроде как версия питона не подходит, но это про 3.5, неужели и 3.6 тоже?

Comment: На линуксах ведь python2 стоит по умолчанию. И pip, по идеи, вызовет python2. А попробуйте `pip3 install PyQt5`

Comment: Попробовал и такой же результат. На винде все пакеты нормально устанавливались, а тут...

Comment: Попробуйте: `sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5`

Comment: Если без виртуальной среды то работает, а в виртуальной среде не получается установить.

Comment: А в виртуалке на что ругается?

Comment: Когда пытаюсь запустить скрипт с консоли, просто выводит ошибку "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'". Короче, не находит модуль.

Comment: `в виртуальной среде не получается установить` т.е. вы про virttenv или в ОС на виртуалке?

Comment: Именно про virttenv.